# Html table does not conform to width of tds when it's inside a container

Tags: html, css

even though I explicitly set the widths:

```
<div id='container'>
<table>

<tr>
<td style='width:200px'>bla1</td>
<td style='width:200px'>bla2</td>
<td style='width:200px'>bla3</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
```

My table gets a random width of 183px. How to make table get 600px width without explictly setting it? I thought specifying width with td's would suffice. Note I'd like to keep it within its container that has a width of 200px and have it scroll. for some reason it works when I don't put it in the container.

Note: I'd like it to scroll within the container without manually setting table width to 600px. This is because in practice all my td's are going to have different widths.

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/fzf3tjdu/

Comment: Would placing ' style="position:absolute" '  within your table be acceptable?

Comment: @YAHsaves no I'd like for it to scroll within the container

Comment: what's with the downvotes?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to set the table width directly? That would seem to solve your problem.

Comment: @YAHsaves because the columns could be of different sizes

Comment: The comment in your fiddle : *how to make table 600px automatically without specifying it..* will never be a thing. Things don't automagically happen, you will have to provide a unit of measure of some kind in most cases when you want it to fit a certain way. Either with absolute or relative or rem, em, percentages. If you set the width of your table to 100%, you can either cascade that value down or change the columns, or rows to a width of that value as desired

Comment: @soulshined you have no idea what you're talking about, see my answer

Comment: that's not the same thing as your table conforming to the width of td's. Perhaps the description is ambigous. regardless, glad you got it working @foreyez

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your table is not 600px wide is because your CSS for the #container is set to 200px. Change it to 600px and that will solve your problem.

Edit:
Whoops, I  noticed you said without specifying 600px.
First remove your 200px width limitation from the #container in css code.
Next, add:

```
table {
width: inherit;
}
```

Extras:
Outside the realm of your question...
If you want a responsive solution, you should consider looking into percentage based, em based, or other units other than specifically defining a pixel value. This also goes with the potential use of min-width/max-width :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: @foreyez just edited my answer. i didn't see your 600px part earlier. :)

Comment: I don't want to inherit the width of the container, I wanted it to be the size of its contents.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by providing a min-width of 200px to the td's. for some odd reason when it's inside a container it needs this.